# max no of columns in infobright

Tags: rdbms, infobright

We store billions of rows in an infobright table which currently has about 45 columns.  We want to add 50 more columns to it.  Will adding these columns bring down the performance of reads?  Is creating a new table for these columns a better option?  Or, since infobright is a column oriented database additions of 50 extra columns not matter much?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "adding these columns" will not "bring down the performance of reads" that do not use the added columns.

I think "creating a new table for these columns" is not "a better option".

Since "infobright is a column oriented database additions of 50 extra columns" should have no effect on the performance of queries that do not use the added columns.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of columns for Infobrigh6t tables is 4096.  However, that is if they are only TINYINT columns.  I would suggest that you do not use more than 1000 columns.  The key though is ensuring that in your SQL query that you do not do a SELECT * FROM.  You should SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName FROM instead for ONLY those columns necessary to resolve your needs.